# AngularJS ng-options dropdown fails for web service response with only 1 value

Tags: angularjs, select

I am using AngularJS $http to populate a dropdown from a web service.  It works fine unless the response has only 1 value (ex: car trims).

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="carYear" ng-options="item.value for item in cars.years" ng-change="updateDdl('make',carYear.value);" >
            <option value="">Select Year</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="carMake" ng-show="cars.makes.length > 0" ng-options="item.value for item in cars.makes" ng-change="updateDdl('model',carMake.value);">
            <option value="">Select Make</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="carModel" ng-show="cars.models.length > 0" ng-options="item.value for item in cars.models" ng-change="updateDdl('trim',carModel.value);">
            <option value="">Select Model</option>
        </select>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('carData', []).controller('carCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.baseWebAPI = 'https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/';
        $scope.cars = {};
        $scope.car = {};

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.baseWebAPI + '/menu/year'
        }).then(function (result) {
            $scope.cars.years = result.data.menuItem;
        });

        $scope.updateDdl = function(t,i){
            switch (t) {
                case "make":
                    $scope.selectedCarYear = i;
                    $scope.webAPI = $scope.baseWebAPI + 'menu/make?year='+i;
                    break;
                case "model":
                    $scope.selectedCarMake = i;
                    $scope.webAPI = $scope.baseWebAPI + 'menu/model?year='+$scope.selectedCarYear+'&make='+i;
                    break;
                case "trim":
                    $scope.selectedCarModel = i;
                    $scope.webAPI = $scope.baseWebAPI +  'menu/options?year='+$scope.selectedCarYear+'&make='+$scope.selectedCarMake+'&model='+i;
                    break;
            }
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $scope.webAPI
            }).then(function (result) {
                switch (t) {
                    case "make":
                        $scope.cars.makes = result.data.menuItem;
                        break;
                    case "model":
                        $scope.cars.models = result.data.menuItem;
                        break;
                    case "trim":
                        $scope.cars.trims = result.data.menuItem;
                        console.log($scope.cars.trims);
                        break;
                }
            });
        };
```

Year, Make, Manf fields work fine but trim fails if there is only 1 trim type without any type of error.

Comment: It's most likely because the ng-options attribute expects an array, and your API is probably returning a single object, because the result set only has the one object. Have you tried checking the type of the resultData returned first? If it isn't an array, you can simply cast it

Comment: That does appear to be the issue - how do I make it be able to work with both 1 value or multiple?

Comment: By casting it to an array - so if you have var obj = {}; then [obj] will make it an array.